# Shadow of War gold currency without microtransactions

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-war

Is there a way to obtain gold currency on Shadow of War without the need to pay money?

Comment: A more in-depth review of the loot box system was done by Kotaku. https://kotaku.com/what-you-need-to-know-about-shadow-of-wars-controversia-1819293793

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get gold by finishing in game quests, for example as quoted in [this link](http://www.gamesradar.com/middle-earth-shadow-of-war-gold-guide/):

> Fortunately, for those that want to get a chance at better loot chests, but don't want to break the bank, you can earn small amounts of Gold by completing challenges. The challenges change each day, and vary quite a bit in objective, but are never too difficult to complete. T**oday, one of my challenges was to recruit two Orc Captains in Minas Morgul for 50 Gold**.
>
> When the game gets a full release, there will also be community challenges that reward Gold. However, as of right now I don't have the information on what those will entail.

(emph mine). This means you get 50 gold for completing this quest without paying any real currency.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: how much is 50 gold? Is that one chest, five, chests, ten chests of half a chest?

Comment: @Shadur depends on the chest you want. There are normal gold chests of 200 or 150 coins, Mithril gold chests of 400 or 600 gold, bundles that sell multiple chests at a discount, themed chests for 240-260 gold and individual boosts. [Kotaku has an in-depth analysis article](https://kotaku.com/what-you-need-to-know-about-shadow-of-wars-controversia-1819293793) where they essentially say that because of the random nature of the orcs you can get and the fact that they're the same level as you, it's better to go in the world and find an orc with the right moves and higher level.